# Twilio. View call cost in web interface

Tags: twilio, phone-call

Can someone help to know, can I see cost of each call at user cabinet in Twilio service?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can see the price of a call on the call details page, linked from the call logs with a URL that would look like this: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls/CALL_SID, in your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls).

[image: The cost is listed on an individual call page, under duration.]

If that's not helpful, you could also build your own call log dashboard with the price on it, using the API. If you [list the calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-example-1), they will come with a [price attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) which you could use for this purpose.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing/in

If you use trial then free. other twilio take per call like this[image]

Comment: what does it mean "free"? I can't see information about costs at all?

Comment: plz check my answer  again

Comment: can you give me link for this page?

Comment: which country u leave select first then

Comment: this will show info about my own calls? or its basicaly information?

Comment: do you have twilio account? I need to view already made calls in my account

Comment: r u android developer??

Comment: I'm php developer

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on 
https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing

Finally found it

Comment: this is standart cost for call per minute. But i need to see next:
for example i called to +12345689, it took 10 minutes, can i see something like 5cent/minute * 10 = 50 cents? And do it for each call that I've have been made?

Comment: hey @user7257758 do u use twilio